# SQL Server parallelism issue

Tags: sql-server, parallelism

I am rather new to SQL Server administrations, I am running an SSIS that never ends...

A) looking at the processes using

```
SELECT r.*, t.text 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) t 
WHERE r.status IN (N'Suspended', N'Running', N'Runnable', N'Pending')
```

I see the session is *SUSPENDED*

B) looking at the actual execution plan using

```
SELECT plan_handle 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests 
WHERE session_id = 55

SELECT query_plan 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_plan (0x06000A00FB4E0A2240615FAE010000000000000000000000)
```

I see 95% of time spent on parallelism

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Assaf

Comment: Is the process blocked? How many CPUs on the box? What is the server's MAXDOP setting?

Comment: Usually there is a root cause (e.g. outdated statistics). Did you look at the wait types for all of the threads in sys.dm_exec_requests? (They won't ALL be CXPACKET, but it's often "blamed" for the wait, when that isn't actually correct.) Can you show the plan somewhere?

Comment: Does the T-SQL complete if you run it outside of SSIS?

Answer (score 1):

Suspended status doesn't tell you much; the wait type tells you the story. I would;

1. [Download and Install sp_whoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com) execute the below command while the processes are suspended to get the leading blocker, it's wait type along the lock graph. This should show the lock areas. (please upload)

> ```
> exec sp_WhoIsActive 
>   @show_own_spid=1, 
>   @show_sleeping_spids=1, 
>   @get_task_info =2, 
>   @get_locks=1, 
>   @get_additional_info=1, 
>   @find_block_leaders=1,
>   @format_output = 0
> ```

2. Setup a SQL blocking report trace. [Here is the link with scripts to set up the blocked report SQL trace](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Blocking/64474/). Set the **blocked process threshold** to 20 secs or higher

Please upload these results for review